# Using gh-pages to deploy to master branch instead of gh-pages branch for USER site

Tags: github, npm, github-pages, npm-scripts

I am new to npm and I followed a video where I realized after that the site was deployed to a project branch. I need to deploy to the User branch (so the master). I used gh-pages to deploy the site which defaults to gh-pages branch on github.

I found an option on gh-pages documentation that will change the publishing branch to master. Here is the snippet

```js
/**
 * This task pushes to the `master` branch of the configured `repo`.
 */
ghpages.publish('dist', {
  branch: 'master',
  repo: 'https://example.com/other/repo.git'
}, callback);
```

Now my biggest issue is since I'm new to npm still, where do I go to add this snippet.

Also here is the repo I'm trying to deploy, but since my master has my dev files and didnt deploy the dist file it wont work. https://github.com/kjh5467/kjh5467.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you still need this answer but just in case anyone else ends here.

To change the default branch of `gh-pages` you can use the `--branch` option in `package.json` as below:

```
package.json

{
     ...
     "scripts": {
         ...
         "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist -b master"
     }
}
```

When you run `npm run deploy`, it will use the master branch (and allow you to use React in your personal user website).

**Important**: be careful when doing this as `gh-pages` removes all the content of that branch before deploying it!!
Move your source code to a different branch first (e.g. source-code) and work there by default.